# Best practise for testing Android Deep Links navigation into activities

Tags: android, unit-testing, kotlin, deep-linking, android-testing

I have an activity for holding a fragment. I created this for being able to run Deep Link to the profile. Also I pass PROFILE_ID as a query parameter. So the whole deep link looks this: "**tigranes://home/profile?profileId=3545664**".

```
class ProfileActivity : BaseActivity() {

    companion object {
        @JvmStatic
        fun newInstance(context: Context, profileId: String): Intent {
            val intent = Intent(context, ProfileActivity::class.java)
            intent.putExtra(ProfileFragment.PROFILE_ID, profileId)
            return intent
        }
    }

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
         super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)

        val profileId: String = intent.getStringExtra(ProfileFragment.PROFILE_ID)
        val transaction = supportFragmentManager.beginTransaction()
        val fragment = ProfileFragment.newInstance(profileId)
        transaction.add(R.id.fragment_container, fragment)
        transaction.commit()
    }
}
```

So my question is what will be the best strategy for writing test checking if this deep link is opening ProfileActivity. I tried to use ActivityTestRule but I wasn't able to find a way for passing a parameters to it.

Comment: The way you are creating your fragment is incorrect. You should be doing the initial FragmentTransaction inside `if(savedInstanceState == null` otherwise you will have overlapping fragments.

Comment: I know :) The question is how to test deep links.

Comment: @TigranGhazinyan Answered that, but as the `ProfileActivity ` looks alike, it might not lead to the desired result... you could still validate the answer by calling `getIntent()`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Method `newInstance()` seems to be utter non-sense, because the `Intent` is being passed to the `Activity`; you should reconsider how that `ProfileActivity` is being constructed, because this is not how it works. `getIntent()` is all you need to get the `Intent` (as the method's name might suggest). Also @EpicPandaForce's suggestion should be taken into consideration, in order to avoid a mess. However, this wasn't the actual question (just telling, because you might claim "it doesn't work").

---

Testing an `Activity` with a deep-link `Intent` works alike this:

```
import android.content.Intent
import android.net.Uri
import androidx.test.ext.junit.rules.activityScenarioRule
import androidx.test.ext.junit.runners.AndroidJUnit4
import org.junit.Rule
import org.junit.runner.RunWith

@RunWith(AndroidJUnit4::class)
class ProfileActivityTest {

    @get:Rule
    var testRule = activityScenarioRule<ProfileActivity>(
        Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(DEEP_LINK))
    )

    @Test
    ...

    companion object {
        val DEEP_LINK = "tigranes://home/profile?profileId=3545664"
    }
}
```

The `activityScenarioRule` depends on:

```
androidTestImplementation "androidx.test.ext:junit-ktx:1.1.1"
```

Please let me know if this works (this would require fixing the `ProfileActivity` in the first place).

Also make sure, that the `intent-filter` in the `AndroidManifest.xml` is setup properly.

Comment: This doesn't work for scenarios where DEEP_LINK is wrong i.e should have `ActivityNotFoundException`.  @Martin Zeitler

Comment: The deep-link cannot be wrong, because of an `intent-filter` in the `AndroidManifest.xml`.., which means your test case is absurd and invalid, because an `intent-filter` would never pick up an unknown URL.

Comment: Over here, I thought tests are a safety net for absurd and invalid cases :)