# ActivityScenario.launch looking for some cached jar

Tags: android, android-instrumentation, activity-scenario

I am running android instrumentation tests and I have the following code:

```
    lateinit var scenario: ActivityScenario<MainActivity>

@Before
fun before(){
    scenario = ActivityScenario.launch(MainActivity::class.java)
}
```

The tests themselves, run great.

However, every time I launch the suite (or an individual test)
I see the following in the log

```
E/System: Unable to open zip file: /data/user/0/com.my.app/cache/dFBYiv5m.jar
E/System: java.io.FileNotFoundException: /data/user/0/com.my.app/cache/dFBYiv5m.jar (No such file or directory)
        at java.util.zip.ZipFile.open(Native Method)
        at java.util.zip.ZipFile.<init>(ZipFile.java:265)
        at java.util.zip.ZipFile.<init>(ZipFile.java:187)
        at java.util.jar.JarFile.<init>(JarFile.java:169)
        at java.util.jar.JarFile.<init>(JarFile.java:106)
        at libcore.io.ClassPathURLStreamHandler.<init>(ClassPathURLStreamHandler.java:46)
        at dalvik.system.DexPathList$Element.maybeInit(DexPathList.java:756)
        at dalvik.system.DexPathList$Element.findResource(DexPathList.java:783)
        at dalvik.system.DexPathList.findResources(DexPathList.java:578)
        at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findResources(BaseDexClassLoader.java:248)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.getResources(ClassLoader.java:839)
        at java.util.ServiceLoader$LazyIterator.hasNextService(ServiceLoader.java:349)
        at java.util.ServiceLoader$LazyIterator.hasNext(ServiceLoader.java:402)
        at java.util.ServiceLoader$1.hasNext(ServiceLoader.java:488)
        at androidx.test.internal.platform.ServiceLoaderWrapper.loadService(ServiceLoaderWrapper.java:46)
        at androidx.test.internal.platform.ServiceLoaderWrapper.loadSingleService(ServiceLoaderWrapper.java:69)
        at androidx.test.core.app.ActivityScenario.<init>(ActivityScenario.java:140)
        at androidx.test.core.app.ActivityScenario.launch(ActivityScenario.java:189)
        at com.my.app.test.authFlow.OnboardingFlowSteps.before(OnboardingFlowSteps.kt:80)
        at org.junit.rules.ExternalResource$1.evaluate(ExternalResource.java:46)
        at org.junit.rules.RunRules.evaluate(RunRules.java:20)
        at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:325)
        at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:78)
        at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:57)
        at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
        at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
        at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
        at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
        at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
        at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
        at androidx.test.ext.junit.runners.AndroidJUnit4.run(AndroidJUnit4.java:104)
        at org.junit.runners.Suite.runChild(Suite.java:128)
        at org.junit.runners.Suite.runChild(Suite.java:27)
        at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
        at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
        at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
        at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
        at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
        at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
        at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:137)
        at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:115)
        at androidx.test.internal.runner.TestExecutor.execute(TestExecutor.java:56)
        at androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner.onStart(AndroidJUnitRunner.java:392)
        at android.app.Instrumentation$InstrumentationThread.run(Instrumentation.java:2189)
```

What is it? Do you know how to get rid of it?

Comment: Possibly related: [Espresso generating FileNotFoundException, when used with Dagger](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58061693/espresso-generating-filenotfoundexception-when-used-with-dagger) ...besides, `ActivityScenario` can be constructed differently; for [example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59922329/549372).

Comment: I'm not using neither dagger nor espresso